# Represent C:\Program Files in XML

Tags: xml, error-handling, path, escaping, cdata

In my XML file I am trying to use a path to a file; it starts like this:

```
<value key="myPath"><![CDATA[C:\Program Files\myFile.exe]]>
```

Then, when I launch my app it always says, can't find file:

> Can't find file C:\Program

So, obviously it's still getting caught up in the space between Program and Files. I thought my CDATA would fix that.

How wrong am I?

Comment: it's not the xml, cdata or no, it's your program that's mishandling the space.  cdata is only a convenient way of not needing to escape <>&

Comment: The CDATA (or XML) has nothing to do with your problem. It's your program that doesn't treat the actual value correctly.

Comment: You guys were right, it was the parser that was messing it up. Thank you for all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were designing this application, I would store URIs rather than filenames. That just seems the right approach in the kind of world where XML is usually used. But of course you can store anything you like in XML, and if the requirement is to store Windows filenames, then you are welcome to do so.

The fact that it doesn't work has nothing to do with the XML. The receiving application that is extracting the filename from the XML and attempting to open the file is doing something wrong: it's either messing up the filename itself, or it's passing it to an API than can't handle filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing double quotes around the path.

```
<value key="myPath"><![CDATA["C:\Program Files\myFile.exe"]]>
```

You probably didn't need to use CDATA either, in case you want to clean it up more.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the XML it may be your app is terminating after the space.

A few possibilities

- Wrapping your path in quotes " "
- Escaping the spaces C:\Program\ Files
- URL Encoding the spaces from space to %20

Without some more info on how your executing the XML its difficult to say.

Answer (score 1):

XML does not mess with your whitespace by default. It also doesn't care about backspaces, colons or the dot before the file extension. Really most of the valid path characters are also valid XML characters. (I think they are actually all valid XML text node content.)

The problem definitely is in the XML processing, not the XML content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&quote;Path%quote;` technique. Quite dirty but works fine,